# Generate three level dependency in case a verb is attached with non verb in dependency parsing

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I am using dependency parsing for a use case in R with the corenlp package. However, I need to tweak the dataframe for a specific use case.

I need a dataframe where I have three columns. I have used the below code to reach till the dependency tree.

```
devtools::install_github("statsmaths/coreNLP")
coreNLP::downloadCoreNLP()
initCoreNLP()
inp_cl = "generate odd numbers from column one and print."
output = annotateString(inp_cl)
dc = getDependency(output)

 sentence governor dependent      type governorIdx dependentIdx govIndex depIndex
1        1     ROOT  generate      root           0            1       NA        1
2        1  numbers       odd      amod           3            2        3        2
3        1 generate   numbers      dobj           1            3        1        3
4        1   column      from      case           5            4        5        4
5        1 generate    column nmod:from           1            5        1        5
6        1   column       one    nummod           5            6        5        6
7        1   column       and        cc           5            7        5        7
8        1 generate     print nmod:from           1            8        1        8
9        1   column     print  conj:and           5            8        5        8
10       1 generate         .     punct           1            7        1        10
```

Using POS tagging with the following code, I ended up with the following data frame.

```
ps = getToken(output)

ps = ps[,c(1,2,7,3)]

colnames(dc)[8] = "id"

dp = merge(dc, ps[,c("sentence","id","POS")], 
     by.x=c("sentence","governorIdx"),by.y = c("sentence","id"),all.x = T)

dp = merge(dp, ps[,c("sentence","id","POS")], 
     by.x=c("sentence","dependentIdx"),by.y = c("sentence","id"),all.x = T)

colnames(dp)[9:10] = c("POS_gov","POS_dep")


  sentence dependentIdx governorIdx governor dependent      type govIndex id POS_gov POS_dep
1         1            1           0     ROOT  generate      root       NA  1    <NA>      VB
2         1            2           3  numbers       odd      amod        3  2     NNS      JJ
3         1            3           1 generate   numbers      dobj        1  3      VB     NNS
4         1            4           5   column      from      case        5  4      NN      IN
5         1            5           1 generate    column nmod:from        1  5      VB      NN
6         1            6           5   column       one    nummod        5  6      NN      CD
7         1            7           5   column       and        cc        5  7      NN      CC
8         1            8           1 generate     print nmod:from        1  8      VB      NN
9         1            8           5   column     print  conj:and        5  8      NN      NN
10        1            9           1 generate         .     punct        1  9      VB       .
```

In case a verb(action word) is attached to a non-verb(non action word), but the  non-verb(non-action word) is connected to other non-verb(non-action words) then one row should indicate the entire connection. Eg: generate is a verb connected to numbers and numbers is a non verb connected to odd.

So the intended data frame needs to be

```
Topic1 Topic2 Action
numbers odd    generate
column  from   generate
column  one    generate
column  and    generate
column  from   print
column  one    print
column  and    print
         .     generate
```

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to have your dependency tree tag print as a verb, rather than a noun.

Try using a sentence with two independent clauses, and see if the root of the second independent clause is tagged as such.

If so, it's a simple walk through the governoridx column. If not, you'll need to address the mechanics of your dependency tree generator.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited the question showing the state I have arrived at. Could you please take a look and share a code sample that  may help me out

Comment: My answer is still the answer. Your question is too broad for a specific "code sample". No one here is going to go find a multi-root dependency tree generator for you. Mark the answer correct, try to find one yourself, and then post another question at the next obstacle you hit.

Comment: That was extremely helpful..thanks a ton...I will surely post when I hit my next obstacle. Great job making the decision for the entire SO population. Thanks again.